The Imperfect Subjunctive of haber - is there a grammar rule or significance of using BOTH forms in the same sentence?
Is there ever a reason for using both the Imperfect Subjunctive forms of a verb in the same sentence?  Can someone give an example of using BOTH in a sentence and why it was used or what the author was trying to convey by doing this?
All I have read so far is that the -ra form is more common, in general.
eg.  hubiera,hubiese 
or hubiéramos,hubiésemos 
I'm convinced that it is related to how the language evolved over time.  One article I stumbled upon here
https://www.thoughtco.com/two-conjugations-one-meaning-3079836
It suggests over time the two forms became to be used identically - so can I infer that at some time in the past, there WAS a different meaning?

You use one or the other, not both.

Si @Lambie hubiera sabido que se pueden usar los dos, no hubiese hecho ese comentario.

Si hubiese [o hubiera sabido [etc.], no habria hecho es comentario.

The form ending in "-era" tends to be more usual, while the one ending in "-ese" sounds more elegant and, where "-era" is more usual, "-ese" seems more sophisticated.
They can be used indistinctly and interchangeably by the same speaker and can be even combined in a conditional sentence, like the one copied below:
 (Source)

Those two forms just show the speaker switched from one to the other. It doesn't show a regular sentence using both forms.

Switching is not only allowed but fully grammatical.

I am not saying it isn't grammatical. You can switch all you like. In speech, one hesitates and changes what one is saying. I'm saying that is not a demontration of using both in a sentence in the way the OP seems to mean: Si fuera rico y fuese simpatico.[etc]...who would say that, right?
